Difficulty mutating single element of NumPy object array
I want to create a numpy array of unique instances of my class.
import numpy as np

class cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

world = np.full((3, 4), cell(), dtype=object)

I try to change the color and id of single cell, but it changes parameters of all of them.

I've also tried to create a blank array and fill it with cell() later but the result was the same.

Numpy array of objects are useless IMHO. Operation on objects are not native like on lists and thus they are slow. In fact, they are slower than lists. It can be convenient for some operations but that's all.This way of programming is not only inefficient but also not the idiomatic way of programming with Numpy. It is better to use multiple arrays of native types. That is a structure/class of array rather an an array of structure/class.

As for your problem, it is certainly because all object references are referencing the same object cell() (which is certainly not what is intended). Lists are generally better to avoid this issue thanks to list comprehension ([cell()]*N would cause the same issue though)

The "num" in "numpy" is short for number/numeric, which is what numpy was designed and optimized to handle. Since your cell class consists of just 4 numeric values, why don't you create an nx4 matrix to hold a list of cell data values?

world contains references to one cell object.  full does not fill it with independent copies.  Think of an object dtype array as a list, and you are putting the same cell object in each element.  You want to create a new cell for each, e.g np.array([cell() for _ in range(10)])

"I want to create a numpy array of unique instances of my class" why do you want to do that? That defeats the entire purpose of numpy arrays. Just use a regular list

But in any case, you will either need to create a list of these objects and then pass it to numpy.array(list_of_cells), or, you can initialize an empty array with dtype=object, then just do something like for i in range(len(arr)): arr[i] = cell() But again, you almost certainly don't actually want that

@Woodford or, a structured dtype!

While numpy arrays are class objects, it isn't efficient or productive to create arrays of custom class objects.  Such an array is basically list like, minus some methods (like append), and plus a few like reshape.  Calculations on such arrays depends heavily on what methods the elements implement (and are nowhere as fast as compiled methods on numeric dtypes).

Why do all values change ?
The reason for this strange behaviour is object references. See "Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument for an explanation of a similar behaviour with list objects.
What actually happens when you create a numeric array with numpy (which should be the only kind of data to work with in a numpy array) is that all numbers have different references in memory. Hence, the line of code
world = np.full((3, 4), 42, dtype=object)

would create an array with 12 distinct numbers in memory, all of them currently having the value 42.
If you were then to change the value of a single cell, then it would not affect the other values of the array, as all of them are distinct objects in memory. This is the classic behaviour, that one could expect to happen also with your line of code.
However, with the line of code
world = np.full((3, 4), cell(), dtype=object)

you only create one instance of the Cell class. So, the numpy array is filled with 12 references to the same object. See How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment? for better understanding of how to copy lists and/or user-defined objects that work with references.
You can also check this answer about copy and deepcopy methods, that you might want in you Cell class.
How to properly create distinct values ?
As mentioned before, a numpy array does not seem like a particularly adapted structure to store generic objects (e.g. Cell instances). See below for other ideas to use numpy in your use case.
If you still want to use numpy, you can try the following syntax which will create 12 instances of Cell objects, so modifying one of them will not impact any of the other:
world = np.array([cell() for _ in range(12)]).reshape((3, 4))

Other way to use numpy with your data type
Depending of what you actual Cell class might be, if it only has numeric data as in your example, you might want to convert the data to a list, and then fill the numpy array to make fast numeric operations, while converting back to Cell class afterwards.
Conversion functions in this spirit might be
import numpy as np


class cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)


def cell2list(c):
    """Return a list with numeric values of the cell."""
    return [c.id, *c.color]


def list2cell(l):
    """Return a cell created from numeric values of the list."""
    c = cell()
    c.id = l[0]
    c.color = tuple(l[1:])
    return c

# Create an empty world array
numeric_dimension_of_cell_class = 4
world = np.zeros((3, 4, numeric_dimension_of_cell_class), dtype=object)

# Convert cells to numpy
world[..., :] = cell2list(cell())

# TODO: Some numeric operations about your cells
world[..., 2:] = 0  # e.g. Keep only Red value

# Convert back numpy to cells
cells = [list2cell(l) for l in world.reshape(-1, numeric_dimension_of_cell_class)]

